# How to create nested dictionary out of the selected keys from the json data

Tags: python

I wanted to retrieve data as

{id:{"branch:"xxx","project":"someproject"}

Wanted to get the data as above

Not able to create nested dictionaries

where the code is giving the last value from the list

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qs
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json


url_list=["http://xxxxxxxxx/+/502789","http://xxxxxxxxx/+/502799"]

gerrit_review_id=[]
branch = {}
project = {}
link ={}
#final_data={}
#enter code here
values=[]
sample={}

for url in url_list:
    project_path = urlparse(url).path.split("+")
    permalink=project_path[1].strip("/")
    gerrit_review_id.append(permalink)
    #print((gerrit_review_id))


for id in gerrit_review_id:
    response = requests.get(f"http://xxxxx/{id}",auth = HTTPBasicAuth('xxxxxx','xxxxx'))
    payload=(response.text[4:]) // getting the bad characters so removed 
    gerrit_data =json.loads(payload)
    sam=('branch','project','_number')
    for items in gerrit_data.items():
        #final_data={}
        for i in sam:
            final_data={}
            if i in gerrit_data.keys():
                    final_data[id]=gerrit_data[i]

print(final_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the hidden url I cannot test the file.

For your question, a dictionary in python is defined as `{key: value}` where `value` can be a dictionary too.

`{id:{"branch:"xxx","project":"someproject"}` simply become:

```py
my_dict = {
  "id":{
    "branch":"xxx",
    "project":"someproject"
  }
}
```

Now to access the value's of `project` we need to access first the dictionary where the value is content.

```py
nested_dict = my_dict["id"]
```

and then we can access the `project`'s values

```py
value = nested_dict["project"]
```

Note that we can access `project` simply writing `my_dict["id"]["project"]`